# How to create Infinitely scrolling grid board for tic tac toe game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, tic-tac-toe, infinitegrid

I'm new to unity and I have been searching all over the internet for about 5 days now about how to create an infinity board for the Tic Tac Toe game and what the winning combination would be in the infinity board Tic Tac Toe game. Can anyone help me, please?

Something like this `https://tic.netlify.app/`

I have tried many different options like generating grid using c# script like this

```
  
    public void GenerateGrid()
    {

        _tiles = new Dictionary<Vector2, Tile>();
        for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < _height; y++)
            {
                var spawnedTile = Instantiate(_tilePrefab, new Vector3(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
                spawnedTile.name = $"Tile {x} {y}";

                var isOffset = (x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 != 0) || (x % 2 != 0 && y % 2 == 0);
                spawnedTile.Init(isOffset);


                _tiles[new Vector2(x, y)] = spawnedTile;
            }
        }

        _cam.transform.position = new Vector3((float)_width / 2 - 0.5f, (float)_height / 2 - 0.5f, -10);
    }
```

But now the question is how can I generate this grid infinitely? To handle this situation i decide to generate new grid when camera move near to edge of the screen, but nothing is happening. Then i decide to use Tilemap , still no sign of hope. can anyone please help me out? How to generate infinite grid board? and what is the best way. archive this?

Comment: The grid must be finite, but even then this is too tricky of a problem to answer in one go. Where is your code to expand the grid when moving the camera?

Comment: Nothing is infinite in computer science. You will run out of memory at some point. I think the best way to make a dynamically expanding grid would be with a dictionary. To save on memory used I'd only keep track of the set tiles.

Comment: @byxor, I'm looking for something like this https://tic.netlify.app/ if you could just guide me how to start or even simple pseudocode

Comment: @Voidsay,  I'm looking for something like this tic.netlify.app if you could just guide me how to start or even simple pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary method as pseudocode:

- have dictionary for set tiles. Recommend [Vector2Int](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.html) or custom long long struct (if you want it bigger) as key and bool as value (true x, false o). You can also have a custom enum as the value if you like the readability.
- have tilemap ready for action

1. When camera moves

   - Determine range of visible tile coordinates using camera position and size
   - lookup dictionary in this range
   - generate tilemap in visible range, fill x o at appropriate coordinates
2. When player makes move

   - determine clicked tile coordinate
   - add new entry to dictionary at coordinate and with the player bool value
   - update view (basically call the same function as 1.)
   - check win condition
   - swap to other player

The tricky part will be to smoothly generate the tilemap. I would recommend to keep the camera gameobject at origin, since the floating point error far out (if you're ever come up with enough patience to get there) is going to be noticeable. Have the tilemap move snap back when it reaches the end. Gameplay wise I'd like to point out that you have a really big, but not truly infinite play field. You will wrap around when you reach the end of the type range of your coordinate. The only danger of crashing would be if you play long enough to run out of memory.